# Working with numbers in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

We're building a webapp using Symfony2 and Oracle. I have a table with some Numeric(10,2) fields. I've mapped this table to an entity with these fields with type decimal, precision 10 and scale 2, and I need to do some calculations with the content of these fields.

My problem is that the values of the fields are converted to strings (using the comma as decimal separator) and I can't do calculations with them. What can I do to operate with this numbers? Must I create a custom mapping type?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. The problem is with Oracle, that is returning all the numeric data with comma as a decimal separator instead of using dots (that is what PHP is expecting).